# Check if ID in one DF exists in another DF (Python 3, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have two dataframes like this:

DF1

```
    ID
    10C
    25Y
    66B
    100W
```

DF2

```
    ID
    10C
    5
    25Y
    66B
```

I want to check to see if any of the values in DF1 appear in DF2 and if so, add either a 1 (if it exists) or 0 (if it doesn't) to a new column such as

```
  ID    Appears
  10C      1
  25Y      1
  66B      1
  100W     0
```

I know this is a really simple problem but it is giving me fits.

Been trying something like

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
df3.fillna(0)
df3['Appear'][df3.ID_x > 0] = 1
df3['Appear'][df3.ID_x = 0] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> np.in1d(df1['ID'], df2['ID']).astype('int')
array([1, 1, 1, 0])
>>> df1['Appears'] = np.in1d(df1['ID'], df2['ID']).astype('int')
>>> df1
    ID  Appears
0  10C        1
1  25Y        1
2  66B        1
3  100        0
```

merge-kind solution, would be like below, but I think using `np.in1d` would be faster.

```
>>> df2['Appears'] = 1
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left').fillna({'Appears':0})
    ID  Appears
0  10C        1
1  25Y        1
2  66B        1
3  100        0
```

Comment: Hi Behzad -- totally my fault but I realized some IDs have letters in them.  Does this solution still work?  I have updated my original question.

Comment: The second solution is the one I am interested in using but whenever I do this, if there is more than one ID that matches (e.g. if 10C appears twice in DF2), it creates duplicates in the original data frame (e.g. two instances of 10C in DF1) -- is there a way around this?

Comment: @user3682157 [`.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)